# Массовое голосование может отменяться в тот же день?

Tags: поддержка, голосование, массовое-голосование

За день получил 20 раз по +10 и -200 за отмену массового голосования.

Я считал, что скрипт отмены запускается по расписанию и обрабатывает вчерашний день, а тут все записи в разделе "сегодня" - как так?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: _Я считал, что скрипт отмены запускается по расписанию и обрабатывает вчерашний день_ - очевидно ты был неправ :-D

Comment: @Grundy, ну может он обновился, или ещё что?

Comment: Меня тоже заголосовали, раньше у меня уже были списания спустя 2-4 часа. Были и через день и через два. Так что я бы не стал утверждать, что оно обрабатывает только вчерашнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [описанию](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/339911) механизма отката голосов при нарушениях правил, скрипт запускается около трех часов ночи:

> Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run

Т.о. если сомнительные голоса были получены в интервале 00:00..03:00 UTC, они, вероятно, будут отменены тем же днём.